# Are moderators chosen from different places on earth?

Tags: support, questions, moderators

I ask because the different local time zones on Earth, for example in USA and China, are not the same.

I mean, if someone from China has posted a question, there will be no moderator at that time!

Or at 5 in morning, if there is no moderator at that time then there will be many flags and uncontrolled questions.

Or are moderators just chosen when they meet the badge requirements?

Comment: The *vast* majority of the moderation on the site is community moderation, not moderation from elected moderators, making this much less of an issue.

Comment: The community elects its moderators freely, there are no geographical restrictions or encouragements. Being in a time zone that isn't covered well yet can be a point in favour of a candidate.

Comment: thanks for understanding me while i have bad english  :) .

Comment: some mods are chosen from Mars, Mercury and the moons of Jupiter...

Answer (score 11):

Any user who meets the requirements can become a moderator, no matter where in the universe he or she is located (network lag becomes an issue as you get out past Mars, however).

The voters may take geographic location into account when deciding on candidates, or they may not.

I recall some discussion the last time around that it might be a good idea to have another* moderator or two located in SE Asia, exactly because of the time zone issue you mention. (See comments under various [2013 nominations](https://stackoverflow.com/election/4).) It's not a guarantee of election, though, nor is it a mark against a candidate. It's just one of many factors that will be taken into consideration.

---

*[Tim Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post) is in that region, and was a moderator for quite a while (now a community manager).

Answer (score 2):

Generally people are free to take into consideration any criteria while electing the candidate.

So if you think, that some time region needs more moderators, choose your candidate among those from that region (there are a few candidates from India, for example).

You should do the same if you think some technology is not enough covered by moderator activity (at least 2 candidates pledged to take care of [android](/questions/tagged/android) tag).

It's a bit too late now, but the question in which hours someone is normally active would be a very good question for moderator candidates.